# Python non convex optimization

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex

I use the package cvxpy form Python to solve a non convex optimization problem which is given as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp




def kl(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return 0.000001
    if b==0:
        return 1000000
    if a==0:
        return -np.log(1-b) 
    return a*np.log(a/b)+(1-a)*np.log((1-a)/(1-b))  

t = 0.5
q = 0.1
p = 0.1

d = cp.Variable()
c = t/(1-t)/(d*kl(a,q))

objective = cp.Minimize(c)
constraints = [ -np.log((a/q-1)*((1-(1-p)/q))) >= d, d >= 0 ]

prob = cp.Problem(objective,constraints)
result = prob.solve()
print(d.value)
print(constraints[0].dual_value)
```

I think the package does not like the function in the objective function, but it's just a guess.
Thank for your help.
Kind regards

Comment: cvxpy is for convex problems only.

Comment: Thx! Is there a package for non convex problems?

Comment: Some global solvers are accessible through Pyomo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Scipy constrained optimisers might be good. Try one of those:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html